# Can I recharge 3.7v 150mah 30C battery using TP4056?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

I think, I need to replace R3 (1.2k) with 10k of TP4046 micro USB module. Then I will get 130mA. Is it correct?

Comment: Show the schematic you're talking about. We have no idea what R3 is or does.

Comment: slip of the keystroke. I meant discharge rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R3(kΩ)  I(mA)  [ref](http://www.buildcircuit.com/how-to-use-micro-usb-5v-1a-lithium-battery-charging-board-charger-module/)
30  50
20  70
10  130
5   250
4   300
3   400
2   580
1.66    690
1.5     780
1.33    900
1.2     1000

So for a 1C charge rate on 150 mAh battery you may replace default R3 1.3k with above.

- 10k to get a 130mA charge rate
- 8.7k to get 150mA rate by interpolation  (8.7*150=130)

1C is safe for charging and if Battery spec allows up to 3C, this may be used for rapid charging at the expense of reduced battery life.

Overdischarging on the 1st use will permanently ruin it.

Comment: Thank you for your great help. I will use 8.6k resistor. Is it okay?